# How do I link a Post Type to a Template in Masterplan?

Tags: posts, themes

I've made a new .php theme page and want to use that file on one of my Post Types. In the Templates part of Masterpress Ive added my Post Type in the availability section.

However, when I view my posts with that Post Type their theme doesn't change. I cannot see where to select the theme on the Edit Post Type page.

Does anyone know how I can select a theme for a particular Post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Masterplan nor Masterpress, however as far as the template hierarchy is concerned, it seems to be no different from the standard Wordpress way of dealing with it – See [Masterpress Docs](http://masterpressplugin.com/docs/developer/recipes/the-current-object)

I assume that if your (Custom) Post Type is correctly registered through Masterpress interface, it should be registered in Wordpress.

So you probably just have to send your PHP template, renamed to `single-{post_type}.php` on your sever, in your current theme folder. For instance if your post type is registered under "trees" (take not-rewrited slug, or [front-end name](http://masterpressplugin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp/files/features/images/post-type-field-sets.v1.png) as it seems to be called in Masterpress), then your PHP file should be named `single-trees.php`

It should then be used automatically by WP when accessing a post from this Post Type.